# PHP ob_start within foreach unexpected resuts

Tags: php, foreach, ob-start

I have the following code

```
foreach($this->load as $count=>$test){
ob_start();
echo $count;
$cached = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
echo $cached
}
```

The foreach should loop 2 times. I want to get

**12**

but I get

**11**

I do not think it is clearing the ob_start.

Any Help please.

Comment: Works for me https://3v4l.org/jd0c6

Comment: Check your source: `$this->load`, it contains what you see. And better end lines like `echo $cached` with a `;`, looks better. Soms indentation would be nice too. ;-) In short: We cannot check it loops twice, but we do know it cannot have two keys like `1`, so probably there's just one key `11` and it loops once.

Comment: OK, I found other things wrong with my code, I agree this code does work.